# New inside a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I noticed the following code from our foreign programmers:

```
private Client[] clients = new Client[0];

public CreateClients(int count)
{
    lock (clients)
    {
        clients = new Client[count];

        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
           Client[i] = new Client();//Stripped
        }
     }
 }
```

It's not exactly proper code but I was wondering what exactly this will do. Will this lock on a new object each time this method is called?

Comment: It is a bad practice to `lock` arrays. Better define additional object for syncronization

Comment: The code as written is wrong, right? Inside the lock shouldn't it be clients = new Client[count], and then clients[i] = new Client();?

Comment: You're right, edited it.

Comment: It simply is not thread-safe. Multiple threads could be creating and using different arrays, some Clinet()'s would  be lost.

Comment: @Henk OP knows it's bad - the question is "what happens" i.e. understanding what is the bad behavior it has.

Comment: @glowc: impossible to say without seeing any threads being created. The __not thread-safe__ verdict should be sufficient though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question of "I was wondering what exactly this will do" consider what happens if two threads try to do this.

```
Thread 1: locks on the clients reference, which is `new Client[0]`
   Thread 1 has entered the critical  block
Thread 1: makes a array and assigns it to the clients reference
Thread 2: locks on the clients reference, which is the array just made in thread 1
   Thread 2 has entered the critical block
```

You know have two threads in the critical block at the same time. That's bad.

Comment: So each time a thread enters it will most likely lock on a new object. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong - it will lock on a new instance every time it's called.

It should look like that:

```
private static readonly object clientsLock = new object();
private static string[] Clients = null;

public CreateClients(int count)
{
    if(clients == null)
    {
        lock (clientsLock)
        {
            if(clients == null)
            {
                clients = new string[count];

                for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                     client[i] = new Client();//Stripped
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

There's no point in locking every time the method is called - that's why the surrounding if clause.

Comment: This will never get in, because you'll never get in your first couple blocks of `if clients != null` It will always be null because the only way to remove it's nullity is inside the `!= null` block

Comment: Yes, it probably should be "if (clients == null)" twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use : 
`private object = new Object();`

```
lock(object){

//your code

}
```

Comment: Given that it's an instance method, I see no reason to use a static lock object.

Answer (score 1):

This `lock` really does nothing.  It locks an instance of an object which is immediately changed such that other threads entering this method will `lock` on a different object.  The result is 2 threads executing in the middle of the `lock` which is probably not what was intended.

A much better approach here is to use a different, non-changing object to lock on

```
private readonly object clientsLock = new object();
private Client[] clients = new Client[0];  

public CreateClients(int count) {     
  lock (clientsLock) {         
    clients = new string[count]; 
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct to doubt this code!

This code will lock on the previous instance each time - this might be the desired effect, but I doubt it. It won't stop multiple threads from creating multiple arrays.